# Compactly supported function on a given compact set

Tags: calculus

Suppose your are given an arbitrary compact set $K\subset\Omega$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is some open set.
Is there a theorem telling that there is some $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\Omega)$ satisfying $\varphi\ge0$ and $\mathrm{supp}(\varphi)=K$?

_______EDIT:
The question arose while I tried to prove the following: Given this open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and some $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\Omega)$ satisfying $\int_\Omega f(x)\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x\ge 0$ for all $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\Omega), \varphi\ge 0$, it holds $f\ge 0$ a.e.
My first idea was to use a contradiction: Assume $\lambda^n(\{f<0\})>0$. Then there is some $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $\lambda^n(\{f<-\varepsilon\})>0$. Hence, using inner regularity of $\lambda^n$, there exists some compact set $K\subset\{f<-\varepsilon\}$ with positive measure. If I now found some $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\Omega)\setminus\{0\},\varphi\ge 0$, s.t. $K=\mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$, the desired contradiction would be established. Unless there is nothing more specific about $K$, I have to rethink my approach.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition for a (relatively) closed $F\subset \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to be the support of a continuous function $\varphi\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is that $F$ be the (relative) closure of an open $U\subset \Omega$, $F = \overline{U}\cap \Omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to be the Cantor set. Then $K$ is closed and bounded and hence compact, but every point in $K$ can be expressed as a limit of points that are not in $K$. Hence, if $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function that vanishes outside $K$, then $\phi$ vanishes on $K$ too. So if $\mathrm{supp}(\phi) \subseteq K$, then $\mathrm{supp}(\phi) = \emptyset \not= K$.

Actually, the above example is over the top (it shows that $K$ can have non-zero measure and still provide a counter-example). Other examples of compact $K$ such that if $\mathrm{supp}(\phi) \subseteq K$, then $\mathrm{supp}(\phi) = \emptyset \not= K$, include non-empty finite sets, and closed bounded countably infinite sets like $\{0\} \cup \{1/n \mathrel{|} 0 < n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$